# Uploading changes to Parse PFUser Object not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I have created a simple iPhone application with a Parse Log In function. I then have a page that a button links to which is where the logged in user can view their profile.

To get this information and load it in the Profile page, I call the following loadData() function from the viewDidLoad():

```
func loadData() {

    // DISPLAY PICTURE CODE
    dpImage.image = UIImage(named: "profilePlaceholder")
    dpImage.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    dpImage.layer.masksToBounds = true

    // Get and set Name and Degree
    fullNameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser()["fullName"] as? String
    degreeLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser()["degree"] as? String

    // Check degreeYear of user and create String
    var degreeYear = String(PFUser.currentUser()["degreeYear"] as Int)

    if (degreeYear == "1") {
        degreeYear += "st Year"
    } else if (degreeYear == "2") {
        degreeYear += "nd Year"
    } else if (degreeYear == "3") {
        degreeYear += "rd Year"
    } else {
        degreeYear += "th Year"
    }

    // Get Group Contribution Rating and add % sign
    var groupContribution = String(PFUser.currentUser()["groupContribution"] as Int) + "%"

    // Set labels of cells
    emailCell.detailTextLabel?.text = PFUser.currentUser().email
    institutionCell.detailTextLabel?.text = PFUser.currentUser()["institution"] as? String
    yearOfDegreeCell.detailTextLabel?.text = degreeYear
    groupContributionCell.detailTextLabel?.text = groupContribution

}
```

This works fine. Then I have an edit button on the Profile page which links (modal segue) to a nearly identical page but with textfields instead of labels for each attribute.

On this Profile Edit page, clicking Save runs the following:

```
@IBAction func saveAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.currentUser()["fullName"] = fullNameTextField.text
    PFUser.currentUser()["degree"] = degreeNameTextField.text
    PFUser.currentUser().email = emailTextField.text
    PFUser.currentUser()["institution"] = institutionTextField.text

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

The viewDidAppear function of the Profile page runs the loadData() function again to refresh the data on the label, which successfully updates the labels to the changed values.

BUT! My issue is that it doesn't seem to actually be uploading my changes to the Parse database. This is because when I log out and re-login to the app as the same user, I do not see the new updated profile attribute values, but the original values before changing them.

How do I push my changes that I am making in the Edit Profile page back to the Parse server?

**NOTE: This is my first post to StackOverflow so let me know if I was not clear enough :)**

Comment: Try saving the current user: [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the information in parse. First off I would start by setting a variable for PFUser.currentUser(). So something like:

```
var UserInfo = PFUser.currentUser()
```

Then you need to save your info in the background. So right before your dismissViewController, user this:

```
UserInfo.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
(success:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void in
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage on setting the variable UserInfo apart from possible readability improvements? Also, can you please explain how I would use that error block? Where do I put my error handling code? (I.e. I will likely push a UIAlert with the error)

Comment: Within that block of code, if the braces, you can put if statements and what not. All this does is save your information into a class in Parse.  So anywhere in between the 2 brackets you see.

Answer (score 0):

You're correctly setting values on the current user but you are not calling one of the save methods.

Try adding `PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground()` after you set the new values on the current user.